# Delete files specified by the output of find: rm thinks argument list is too long.

Tags: find, rm

When I run the following command, it gives me an error:

```
$ rm -f `find /home/domain/imap/domain.com/*/Maildir -mtime +190 | grep -E '/cur/|/new/'`
-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long
```

How can I run it without the error? (Or how can I put it in `.sh`?)

Answer (score 9):

Well I would be tempted to do something like this instead, making the entire operation a single command.

```
find /home/domain/imap/domain.com/ -mtime +190 \
     \( -ipath '*/Maildir/new/*' -o -ipath '*/Maildir/cur/*' \) \
     -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way: create a loop, getting the result via the pipe

```
find [expression] | while read; do [do something with $REPLY, for example] echo "$REPLY"; done
```

or a temporary file:

```
FILE="OUT_`date`"
find [expression] > $FILE
while read; do
   [do something with $REPLY, for example] echo "$REPLY"
done < $FILE
```

Note that if you do a "rm", an argument *may look like an option*. Consider a file that just happens to be named '-rf'. It is therefore recommended to write `rm -- "$FILE"` or `rm "./$FILE"` (or both) or else `rm "$PATH/$FILE"` if the deletion does not start from the current directory. The single-liner with `find` does not have that problem. In order to avoid a possible aliasing for `rm` to a command with options, explicitly call `/bin/rm`.